Flawed paint has lead layer: Peel Away or Pro?
We just moved into house built in 1920. Of course it has lead paint, but we thought only outside after testing with an amateur swab kit.
An inept painter decades ago painted right over the varnish without sanding, causing "crazing" on all the interior trim (see photo). Then the owners "touched up" some of the cracks with a mismatched off-white (which re-cracked), so it looks dreadful.
 
So we developed a plan -- and started -- to strip the interior woodwork ourselves using Peel Away, fully refinishing some with stain, repainting others. We did a door; it came out beautiful! Then we started the doorframe.
The door we were able to do outdoors, but it makes us nervous to sand inside. So after stripping, I did another swab test and discovered that the bottom paint layer, apparently missed in the prior test, is lead.
After the expected freak-out, we are not sure how to proceed. Online sources seem to say Peel Away is exactly what you should use, but if course they also say amateurs should not be removing lead paint, at least if they don't want long-term health problems.
My question for you: should we leave it intact and find another approach to cover the crazing? keep going with the Peel Away but take better personal precautions (mask, gloves)? Hire an abatement pro, which we can't really afford since we are already paying one to do some of the windows -- and not paying one to do the exterior since the bid was $60k for a 1600 sqft house. 
